# What's the most precision you might lose if you use double to convert a currency value to another currency and back?

Tags: java, double, currency, bigdecimal, double-precision

I know the problem of doubles due to base 2 calculations:

```
var total: Double = 0.1
total *= 0.1
total /= 0.1
println(total) // 0.10000000000000002
```

I understand that BigDecimal should be used for money related calculations, but in my case the little precision loss is acceptable, cuase all the currency calculation I need to do is convert currency C1 to currency C2 and back to currency C1. The only thing is that the two values of C1 after this conversion should match, when I show the result to customer with 5 decimal precision.

Now I'm trying to figure out, how much the value might drift over this conversion at worst case scenario? What are the numbers that might cause the worst case scenario?

Comment: the question don't about `java`

Comment: You can lose whole number precision as well as small decimal precision.

Comment: Floating-point rules are often language-specific, and Java goes into some detail. The tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read the description of [double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> The 11 bit width of the exponent allows the representation of numbers with a decimal exponent between 10^−308 and 10^308, with **full 15–17 decimal digits precision**.

Since you want 5 fraction digits, that means you're ok up to max. 10 integral digits.

Or you could test it. Sometimes empirical evidence is more convincing:

```java
double value = 0.00009;
while (true) {
    String nextDown = String.format("%.5f", Math.nextDown(value));
    String nextUp   = String.format("%.5f", Math.nextUp(value));
    if (! nextDown.equals(nextUp))
        break; // loss of precision to 5 decimals
    System.out.printf("Good: %.5f%n", value);
    value = value * 10 + 0.00009;
}
System.out.printf("Bad: %.5f%n", value);
```

*Output*

```
Good: 0.00009
Good: 0.00099
Good: 0.00999
Good: 0.09999
Good: 0.99999
Good: 9.99999
Good: 99.99999
Good: 999.99999
Good: 9999.99999
Good: 99999.99999
Good: 999999.99999
Good: 9999999.99999
Good: 99999999.99999
Good: 999999999.99999
Good: 9999999999.99999
Bad: 99999999999.99997
```

Yup, 10 is good, 11 bad.

Comment: While this is true, this only shows that you have the definition to represent that precision.  Actually doing calculation between floats is much more susceptible to imprecision.  For example `System.out.println(.0009*999999999.99999);` is incorrect.  You can check it here http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Your example doesn't loose precision. Sure, then entering that on the site you listed, the *tooltip* will show `09` at the end, but that is with 16 digits. When you click the calculate button (`=`), the result is correctly displayed as ending in `1` with 15 digits of precision. So, the stated 15 digits of precision has not been exhausted (yet).

Comment: But Java says the answer is 899999.9999999909.  (Compile and run that line)  Wolfram Alpha says its 899999.999999991.  Also, the original example the OP says is also well within length of 15.

Comment: Also, the issue you're describing where the tool tip is different than the actual answer is a demonstration of the problem.  The tool tip is being generated on the fly with double precision.  When you hit enter, it actually sends it to the server for accurate precision.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Yes, these are the well-known fallacies of use double-precision math, and if you round the result to **15** digits, you get the right answer, in this case at least. The question was however not general, but specifically about an amount of 5 fraction digits, converted to another currency and back, at what point would the result no longer be accurate to 5 fraction digits. My answer that OP should be good up to 10 integral digits still stand.

Answer (score 1):

A `double` as in [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) will maintain 15+ *significant* decimal places if properly rounded to/from Decimal.

Using fixed place math: with 15 *significant*  decimal places and OP needing 5 places after the decimal point, that leaves 10 digits to the left of the decimal.

```
x,xxx,xxx,xxx.xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to never store or transfer the C2 amount anywhere. Instead, store or transfer the C1 amount and the exchange rate. That way, you can compute and display the C2 amount whenever you need it, and you'll always have the exact original C1 value available.

If you absolutely have to store C2 and later recompute C1 from it, it will be fine as long as you use rounding rather than truncation, as you risk that the recomputed result will be e.g. 0.0199999999999. (And as @Andreas pointed out in his answer, there's a limit to how many digits you can support in this way.)

Comment: The problem is that C1 is entered by user, and we need to store all values in C2. So although we do save the rates as well, the conversion from C1 to C2 and back to C1 is inevitable.

Comment: How about storing C1 as well, then?